# HttpWebResponse not responding from PHP

Tags: c#, php, http

So I have this code in C#.

```
    private void SendMessage()
{
    // this is what we are sending
    string post_data = "loginIdPost=" + 2 + "&" + "contentPost=" + absenceInputField.text;

    string uri = "<URI IS HERE>";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
    WebRequest.Create(uri); request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    request.Method = "POST";

    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);


    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();


    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();




    Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
    Debug.Log(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());

    Debug.Log(response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
```

It sends some information to a PHP file, which then puts data into my database. The data is being successfully sent, but the HttpWebResponse is coming back blank. It returns "", an empty string.

This is my PHP code.

```
    <?php

//Id
if (isset($_POST["loginIdPost"]))
{
  $loginId = $_POST["loginIdPost"];
} 
else 
{
  $loginId = null;
}


//Content
if (isset($_POST["contentPost"]))
{
  $content = $_POST["contentPost"];
} 
else 
{
  $content = null;
}

try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("Connection String");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
    die(print_r($e)); 
}

$sth = $conn->prepare('Sql Query is here');
$sth->execute('details of execution are here');
echo "Success";

//Check Connection
if(!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting an empty string back, when I'd expect to be getting "Success" back. Again, no errors in the php code as the SQL query does insert data into my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by just removing Console.Writeline.